# Efficient subsetting in Rcpp (equivalent of the R "which" command)

Tags: r, if-statement, rcpp, syntactic-sugar

In Rcpp, there are various "Rcpp sugar" commands that permit nice vectorised operations in the code. In the code below I move across a data frame, break it into vectors, then use the "ifelse" and "sum" sugar commands to compute the mean of v over the rows where x equals either y or y+1. All seems to work correctly.

**Just wondering if there is a neater way than this - e.g. an equivalent of the "which" command that gives index points satisfying a particular condition?** There seems to be a facility available as "find" in Armadillo but that means using incompatible object types (you can't use "find" and "ifelse" together).

On the same topic, **is it possible to get "ifelse" to accept a compound logical condition?** In the example below, for instance, the definition of indic is formed of two "ifelse" commands, and it would obviously be cleaner as one. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Look forward to hearing your responses :)

```
require(Rcpp)
require(inline)

set.seed(42)
df = data.frame(x = rpois(1000,3), y = rpois(1000,3), v = rnorm(1000),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

myfunc1 = cxxfunction(
    signature(DF = "data.frame"),
    plugin = "Rcpp",
    body = '
            using namespace Rcpp;
            DataFrame df(DF);
            IntegerVector x = df["x"];
            IntegerVector y = df["y"];
            NumericVector v = df["v"];

            LogicalVector indic = ifelse(x==y,true,ifelse(x==y+1,true,false));
            double subsum = sum(ifelse(indic,v,0));
            int subsize = sum(indic);
            double mn = ((subsize>0) ? subsum/subsize : 0.0);

            return(Rcpp::List::create(_["subsize"] = subsize, 
                                      _["submean"] = mn
                                     ));
            '
            )

myfunc1(df)

### OUTPUT:
# 
# $subsize
# [1] 300
# 
# $submean
# [1] 0.1091555
#
```

Comment: 'Rcpp sugar' has a lot of niceties, but it doesn't have everything.  Someone needs to cook up a `which()` variant, I suppose.  Patches welcome.

Comment: Of course... and what it does have is great. As I say, there's an RcppArmadillo `find` that seems to do the right thing, but I was just curious whether the "double ifelse" approach above is an egregious blunder or is pretty much the best sugar hack at the moment...

Answer (score 3):

Rcpp (>= 0.10.0) implements the **|** operator between two logical sugar expressions. So you can do:

```
require( Rcpp )

cppFunction( code = '
List subsum( IntegerVector x, IntegerVector y, NumericVector v){
    using namespace Rcpp ;

    LogicalVector indic  = (x==y) | (x==y+1) ;
    int subsize          = sum(indic) ;
    double submean       = subsize == 0 ? 0.0 : sum(ifelse(indic,v,0)) / subsize ;

    return List::create( _["subsize"] = subsize, _["submean"] = submean ) ;
}
' )
subsum( rpois(1000,3), rpois(1000,3), rnorm(1000) )
# $subsize
# [1] 320
# 
# $submean
# [1] -0.05708866
```